# Digital persona fingerprint verification takes a lot of time

Tags: performance, template, vb.net

I'm using Digital Persona U.are.U 4000b fingerprint reader and I have this function that verifies the fingerprint from SQL server

My problem is the loop because it takes a lot of time to compare the templates.

Please give me some advice on how can I optimize or revise my code.

CODE:

```
Protected Sub Process(ByVal Sample As DPFP.Sample)
    con = New SqlConnection

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Test;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Passw0rd"

    Dim command As String = "SELECT * FROM Bio_Emplist"

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command, con)
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dtb)
    If dtb.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        rowCount = dtb.Rows.Count
        Try
            For Each dr As DataRow In dtb.Rows
                Dim fpt As Byte() = CType(dr("Fpt"), Byte())

                Dim ms As New MemoryStream(fpt)
                Dim tmpObj As DPFP.Template = New DPFP.Template
                Dim verify As DPFP.Verification.Verification = New DPFP.Verification.Verification

                Template = tmpObj
                tmpObj.DeSerialize(fpt)

                DrawPicture(ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample))

                Dim features As DPFP.FeatureSet = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification)
                ' Check quality of the sample and start verification if it's good
                If Not features Is Nothing Then
                    ' Compare the feature set with our template
                    Dim result As DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result = New DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result()
                    verify.Verify(features, Template, result)
                    'UpdateStatus(result.FARAchieved)

                    If result.Verified Then
                        MakeReport("The fingerprint was VERIFIED.")

                        empID = dr("EmpID")
                        empFName = dr("FName")
                        empLName = dr("LName")
                        SetVerifyText(empID, empFName, empLName)
                        Exit Try
                    Else
                        FailedVerifyText()
                        If rowCount = 1 Then
                            MakeReport("The fingerprint was NOT VERIFIED.")
                        Else
                            rowCount = rowCount - 1
                            MakeReport("Finding Match...")
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using parallel.ForEach?

Answer (score 1):

Remove everything that is repeated in the loop and return/do the same thing. Put them outside the loop. Example, this draw the same image every time, you only need it once.

```
DrawPicture(ConvertSampleToBitmap(Sample))
```

And this seems to get the same feature every time.

```
Dim features As DPFP.FeatureSet = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification)
```

Comment: I put the functions outside the loop it speeds up but I encountered another problem I have more than a thousand data now and it takes like 10 seconds to match a fingerprint. Thanks by the way